# FCM - why no longer support FCM direct channel in newer Firebase Admin SDK?

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, firebase-admin

I am trying to implement server for FCM to send notifications to android/iOS devices.

I need to send data-only notifications to both android and iOS but iOS seems very unstable for background notifications. (even though the app is in foreground, I often not get message at all.)

When I test with legacy FCM REST server with FCM direct channel, it works great on iOS but this is not an option for me as newer Admin SDK doesn't support direct channel.

Is there any reason to remove support for FCM direct channel in newer Admin SDK?  I see all Firebase docs recommend to use Admin SDK but not sure why they removed the support for direct channel.

Comment: Hi. This would be better answered by Google themselves (not regular SO users) since this is a business decision. Have you tried reaching out to them about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken FCM [sender-side APIs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) never explicitly supported a direct channel option. As a sender your options were to either specify a device registration token or a topic. These options are present in the newer FCM sender-side APIs (i.e. Admin SDK) as well.

Direct channel is a receiver-end option. I see this option was recently deprecated in [the iOS SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/4710). Folks who work on that repo should be able to provide you more context around that decision. Also if you're experiencing issues with background notifications on iOS I'd recommend you file a bug for the iOS SDK, and try to get it fixed.